# I am trying to enable Virtual Machine Platforms feature but it gives error. I tried enabling it through cmd but still it gives an error. Error:14003

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

I am running Windows 11 64 bit.

[image]
[image]

I tried enabling it through the command `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart` but it could not enable.
It failed even when I tried manually. I have tried searching Microsoft solutions for this issue but it suggests some other issue regarding NetFramework 3.5. Please tell what to do, I cannot run docker without this.I have tried restarting the system but nothing works.

Comment: @John - The second screenshot shows that, the feature isn't installed on the system, so the author won't be able to enable it.

Comment: @codedpool - What edition of Windows 11 are you running?  What version of Windows 11 are you running? This error has **nothing** to do with .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: @John I have windows 11 Home Single Language OS version 22H2 (OS Build 22621.2428). I tried enabling Virtual Machine Platform from the control panel, Programs and features. It doesn't work.

Comment: Upgrade to Windows Pro to enable the features

Comment: @Ramhound There is an option for Virtual Machine Platform in Turn Windows Features on or off but when I click on it and proceed further I get an error. Docker won't run without this, is there some other way to run docker?

Comment: @John Is there some other way to run docker without upgrading to pro?

Comment: @John I checked....there is no such binding that Virtual Machine platform won't work on Windows 11 home....can you think of some other possibility that is causing the error?

Comment: @codedpool - Docker on Windows requires that particular feature, and the only alternative to running Docket within Windows, is running Docker within WSL which also requires it.

Comment: @John - "Upgrade to Windows Pro to enable the features" - Why? Virtual Machine Platform can be installed on Windows 10 11 Home Single Language. The author upgrading to Windows 11 Professional would NOT resolve their current situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error was for my system only. I had to reset my pc and after that I was able to enable virtual machine platform and now I can use Docker.

Note: Maybe due to this error there was a problem in local reset as well and I had to cloud reinstall windows.